# How to align a TextView center horizontally in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to align a TextView center horizontally in jetpack compose? Here is my code

```
Text(
  text = "Title of ModalBottomSheet",
  style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall,
  modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp)                        
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to choose one of the [standard layout components](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/layouts/basics#standard-layouts) (`Row`, `Column`, `Box`, `BoxWithConstraints`) and wrap your `Text` composable with it.

Using `Row` you could horizontally center your `Text` as follows:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    Text(
        text = "Title of ModalBottomSheet",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp)
    )
}
```

Using `Column`:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    ....
{
```